# Failed to resolve: com.google.gms.google-services:15.0.1:

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have installed play services in sdk tools and added following libs though it shows the problem

```
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.gms.google-services:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'

    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `com.google.gms.google-services:15.0.1` from dependencies, that is a gradle file plugin not an dependency.

```
def mySupportVersion = "26.1.0"

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$mySupportVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$mySupportVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$mySupportVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.1"
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

You should use `def` for flexibility when changing version.

Comment: can you do me a favour??

Comment: @DadhichSourav that was problem in your code, if no another problem persist, you can paste error log.

Comment: @Khemraj You shouldn'y use def. Firebase Android SDKs and Google play services now have independent version number. Check https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html

Answer (score 1):

The options can be

```
change versions of play services
 remove unused services
 if using maps, check permission of google place api
[https://firebase.google.com][1] should be proper configured
google-play.json file should be updated with project.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think unchecking `Offline work` option may solve the problem. Check My Answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51611606/6444297).

Answer (score 0):

### A lot of problems can cause this issue:

**1) Check if you have Maven/Google repository on your top level main build.grade (can be found on your project root folder):**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

**2) Check if you have the correct library number on your module App build.grade (can be found on \app) :**

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages

**3) Check buildToolsVersion and targetSdkVersion on your module App build.grade (can be found on \app):**

Sometimes it's not possible to download anything if buildToolsVersion is not set to the new version. Check this site: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools

**4) Check internet connection and firewall issues**

This is so simple, but nobody checks...

**5) Check if Android Studio is set to Offline Work:**

```
File ->
Other Settings ->
Default Settings -> 
Build, Execution, Deployment ->
Build Tools ->
Gradle -> Uncheck Offline Work
```

**6) If nothing works, click on Android Studio "clean project" and then "invalidade cache/restart":**

```
Build->Clean Project
File->Invalidade Cache/Restart
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

> just change the play service version to 15.0.0 and sync the gradle