# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0,16.0.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting this error:
Here is my build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding.enabled = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20"
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.paytm.pgsdk:pgsdk:1.0.8'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and Here is my build.gradle(Project: myApp)

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have checked other solutions, most of them suggest to add

`maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`

to build.gradle of project. I have already tried this but I am still getting same error.

I am on android studio 3.0.
I have also tried adding `google()` instead of maven (another suggestion)

Comment: I personally have the same issue, and one time I was able to grab a line `Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/15.0.2/firebase-messaging-15.0.2.pom' CODE 500`. So there is quite a big chance of google repos being broken right now

Comment: @AnkushRishi I installed android studio in android studio in another local account and it worked, probably you need to reinstall android studio and sdks

Comment: I think no need to reinstall android studio in my case i just `Clean Project` and then `Rebuild Project` and it works.

Comment: @AnirudhBagri: Check my answer, please.

Comment: Files->invalidate cache and restart worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

**OPTION 1:**

**Follow the below instruction to resolve it.**

> Project-level build.gradle

**use**

```
maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
```

**instead of**

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

**OPTION 2:**

> Project-level build.gradle

`google()` repository should be 1st priority

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**OPTION 3:**

**Follow the below steps to resolve it.**

**Step1:**

> Project-level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services plugin
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } // For Ucrop
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } // Google's Maven repository - FCM
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/azeesoft/maven'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Step2:**

> App-level build.gradle

I have update One Signal version.

**use**

```
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.11.1'
```

**instead of**

```
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.9'
```

Comment: I can't believe it but option 1 apparently solved it for me.

Answer (score 6):

Go to File → Other Settings → Default Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Build Tools → Gradle → uncheck `Offline work` option.

Comment: Has this answer (written like several dozen times) ever helped anyone? I don't think so, this issue is always related with incorrectly set up dependencies or Google repos being messed up. So why post this useless "tip" each and every time?

Comment: @GeorgySavatkov: Yes Georgy, It solved my same problem.

Comment: It didn't work for me! I tried all the possible suggestions in the forum :(

Comment: If it still does not work, check your internet connection.

Comment: This alone didn't help, however doing: Invalidate caches and restart after this worked fine (it didn't by itself).

Comment: @DakshAgrawal if he can connect to https://stackoverflow.com/ to ask question why would his internet connection is the problem

Comment: @MuhammadAsyraf However, in some cases it is not possible to access. It may not even be due to the lack of internet access, for example due to the country's IP inability to access that address . Like countries that are under US sanctions. Like Iran

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue while use OneSignal to handle push notifications in my android application.

The solution is to add the exclude clause to its' dependency:

```
implementation ('com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.8.3'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

in the app folder, then add any other missing dependency manually such as:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:16.1.0'
```

The problem is that OneSignal SDK contains Google Play Service dependency that are not of the same version with the latest version of gms and firesbase  I used in the app.

So I suggest you figure out a dependency you added that uses google play service in the project and use the exclude clause on it. Though your gradle should build if your system is connected to the internet.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I was using a VPN for internet connection. I closed VPN and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using the VPN solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and I was using a proxy before. I figured out that my proxy is not working any more so i went to settings and changed the proxy config to Automatic but still the same error was being shown.

I finally found that the proxy was also automatically set to gradle as well but when I disabled it, it wasn't removed from my gradle config. so I went to `C:Users/User/.gradle/gradle.properties` and in that file there was something like this:

```
## For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
#enter code here
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
#
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
#Sat Aug 31 18:23:27 IRDT 2019
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.http.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.https.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8118
```

so I just edited this file and **commented the last 4 lines** and it solved my problem.

I am also using a VPN service.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was...

I can run the project... but suddenly this error came up.

After few tried "Try Again" Solution but not solving.


Finally after few minutes wasted. I Try Clean Project. And Rebuild. Tadaaaa it work.

i dont know if this will help anybody but it solve my issue. hope it solve yours.

Answer (score 0):

Open top-level build.gradle file and add  google-services:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

also if you already have it added simply update google-service and gradle to the latest

Answer (score 0):

If this problem occurred to you suddenly, it may be that it was corrupted while generating the apk. This rarely happens

**Solution: rebuild tasks**

[you can see it in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPpqc.png)

Answer (score 0):

An update of the repository to the latest version solved the problem for me.

```js
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.1'
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I just changes my just changes my project level build Gradle and other dependencies to the latest and the Google Maps dependency in app level build gradle to 10.0.0.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried adding this in your dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.0'
```

Comment: Try to **Invalidate Cache/Restart**

Comment: @JoshuaStephen I have tried Invalidate cache/restart. It still won't work

Answer (score -2):

Just Build → Clean Project worked for me