# Unable to resolve dependencies with Android Studio and Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Following are the error I get, please help me!

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0.
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.3.
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[17.2.0].
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:[17.2.0].
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:[17.2.0].
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath':
>
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0.
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath':
>
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.3.
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath':
>
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[17.2.0].
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath':
>
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:[17.2.0].
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:[17.2.0].
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0.
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.3.
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[17.2.0].
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:[17.2.0].
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:[17.2.0].

```js
//app level build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hfad.firebaselinkedin"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'



}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

```html
//project level build.gradle

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:\[15.0.0,16.0.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822138/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv)

Comment: check if you have proper internet connection

Comment: My internet connection is good! I'm using mobile data(hotspot) to sync it inorder to avoid all these extra works involved with proxies of my wifi

Answer (score 1):

### Update

1. Try "File"->"Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and restart"
2. Try to clean up your .gradle and .idea directory under your project
   root directory.

---

> Go to File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings (**Setting for new project** in newer versions) -> Build, Execution,
>   Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> And uncheck Offline work option.

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51611606/7765316)

And if you are using VPN, please close it or change IP before syncing because some IP are blocked by Google because they may be used to make DDOS attack against google

**If above steps did not help you, try it in your project level** build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }           
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } // Google's Maven repository - FCM
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/azeesoft/maven'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried all above, still giving me the same error. I am using Mobile data via hotspot, so I do not think internet is the problem here. And my offline work is always unchecked.

Comment: I added more steps above in the update session, Could you try these aswell?

Comment: Apparently its giving me the same error. Not sure what is happening.

Comment: The last step is "Uninstall ur Android studio and reinstalls a newer version..."That's all I know now

Comment: I am already using the latest version, Android Studio 3.5.1. I am able to connect my project to all most all the firebase services except the analytics.