# Error: cannot access zzbfm class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm not found

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1.3

I get the following error when trying to build my application:

error: cannot access zzbfm
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm not found

Here is my build.gradle file code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "myapplicationid"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 12
    versionName "1.0.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
signingConfigs {
    key {
        keyAlias 'anavasis'
        keyPassword 'anavasis'
             storeFile file('jks_file_path')
        storePassword 'anavasis'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/anim'] } }
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
//compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
compile 'io.ticofab.androidgpxparser:parser:0.2.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

compile 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'


 }
```

I have checked the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50732851/1465756 but I do not have multiple firebase versions.

If I delete the 3 rows of compile firebase the app is running with no problems BUT I guess I should have them in my build.gradle.

Answer (score 3):

In the top level gradle file use the following:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

To be able to use the latest firebase verisons, also upgrade the Android Studio to version 3.1

> If you're not using Android Studio 3.1 to develop your app, you will need to upgrade in order to get the correct version checking behavior within the IDE.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html

---

Also update:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
```

into this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'
```

> Note: Don't use the combined play-services target. It brings in dozens of libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Check this also:

[Android | Cannot add all Google libraries for version 15.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381727/android-cannot-add-all-google-libraries-for-version-15-0-1/51381916#51381916)

Comment: I have the android studio 3.1.3 and in my project gradle I added the classpaths you suggested (also tried com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3 as suggested by android studio) but nothing worked

Comment: Why are u using compile thought and not implementation?

Comment: What is the difference? I tried to turn compile to implementation but again it didn't work

Comment: I was just wondering because it was deprecated in the new gradle https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration#new_configurations (nothing to do with firebase)

Comment: check the update @arniotaki You need to also update the google services libraries, just saw that you are using that

Comment: I changed as you suggested but instead of 15.0.1 I used 12.0.1 as suggested by android studio because 15.0.1 fails to build gradle. After that changes I get the error error: cannot access zzbgl class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309559/failed-to-resolve-com-google-gms-google-services15-0-1#51611685 @arniotaki? ( I even added it in the note that you shouldnt use the combined play-services target)

Comment: It is unchecked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177102/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-arniotaki).

Comment: Please upvote the answer and mark it as correct if it helped you, thank you!