# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms: play-services: 15.0.1

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Good morning,

I ask for help with this error. I am using **Android Studio 3.1.3**

> Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms: play-services: 15.0.1

**I am using build.gradle(Module:)**
[image: I am using build.gradle]

Comment: Did you try to change version of play services?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309559/failed-to-resolve-com-google-gms-google-services15-0-1